# Defining functions in a namespace declared in a seperate header file (C++)

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

I have a problem that ive been looking at for a bit, and being new to C++ i don't even know if this is possible. I'm trying to replicate a body of code thats in a programming book but when i try to use it in Visual Studio i get an error that tells me that "the function cannot be defined in the current scope".

If i take it out of the "Records" namespace it works fine.

So, is this body of code legal or is there a quirk about this syntax i just don't know?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;
namespace Records {
Employee::Employee()
: mFirstName("")
, mLastName("")
, mEmployeeNumber(-1)
, mSalary(kDefaultStartingSalary)
, mHired(false)

}
```

Comment: What does Employee.h look like?

Comment: `Employee` is not a member of the `Records` namespace, it's a member of the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need a body on your constructor:

```
namespace Records {
Employee::Employee()
: mFirstName("")
, mLastName("")
, mEmployeeNumber(-1)
, mSalary(kDefaultStartingSalary)
, mHired(false)
{
}

}
```

And `Employee` must be declared in the `Records` namespace in Employee.h as well.

Comment: Thanks, i copied and pasted it from the book assuming the syntax could of been different.